# How to send information to a newly instantiated Backbone collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have an API that filters a set of objects based on the ID present in the URL, like so:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/goal_update/?goal__id=12&format=json
```

I have a collection that does a GET request on the above URL. Here is the code for the collection:

```
  var GoalUpdateList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    // Reference the Goal Update model
    model: GoalUpdate,

    // Do HTTP requests on this endpoint
    url: function() {
      return "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/goal_update/?goal__id=" + this.goal_id + "&format=json";
    },

    // Set the goal ID that the goal update list corresponds to
    initialize: function(goal_id) {
      this.goal_id = goal_id;
    },

  });
```

I want to pass in the ID when I create a new instance of the collection, so I created a view that has this code:

```
this.collection = new GoalUpdateList(this.model.get("id"));
```

It thinks that I am passing in model parameters, though. I am trying to pass in information that tells the collection what URL to use. So it runs the ID through a validate function and messes up the rest of the backbone code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backbone's collections expect model data as the first parameter, as you've already noted. But you can specify a second parameter as an object literal, like other Backbone objects. Just pass `null` or `undefined` as the first parameter, and then in your collection `initialize` method, get the `options` as the second parameter.

```
GoalUpdateList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  initialize: function(data, options){
    this.goal_id = options.goal_id;
  }

});

new GoalUpdateList(null, model.get("goal_id"));
```